# How do I change the 'alt gr' key to a context menu key in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: keyboard

I recently got a new laptop and there is no Menu Key, something I use very frequently.

In the same area is the 'alt gr' key, which I have no need for.

I tried using:

```
setxkbmap -option menu:ralt_rctrl
```

and

```
xmodmap -e 'keycode 92 = Menu'
```

but neither seem to have an effect.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You could try and install `gnome-tweak-tool` and set the key alternative there. I am not sure, but I think there is an option to remap the AltGr. Are you sure you don't need it e.g. for typing @ or € or µ and those symbols? Ctrl+Alt is not the same as AltGr - this only works on Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to find an answer to this.

I used the command:

```
xmodmap -e "keysym ISO_Level3_Shift = Menu"
```

and had it run on startup.

My altgr key now acts as a Context Menu Key

Comment: Thanks for the solution, is there a list or something where you could find those keys ? I want to make my Alt work as a Context Menu and vise versa.

Comment: @GeorgeDimitriadis http://wiki.linuxquestions.org/wiki/List_of_Keysyms_Recognised_by_Xmodmap and https://superuser.com/questions/819414/order-of-keysym-in-xmodmap-config-file

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response mate, I have already changed my apple keyboard to a **normal** one.